# Importing models from deployed Django project in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, scrapy

I have been working in two projects for a while. One is a Django project where I have a web and all my logic (models, algorithms, etc). The other one is a Scrapy project. This one is the one that take care of collecting new data that it's being stored in the Django Database.

While I was working locally there wasn't any problem but now that I've deployed both projects to two different Heroku apps I began to have this problem:

My scrapy project is importing the Django models in this way: in my settings.py in my scrapy project I've this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/guillermo/Documents/project/django_project') #(2)

import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project.settings'
```

and then in my files where I need a Django model I do this:

```
from base_project.models import New
```

where New is a model in my app "base_project".

Now, I don't know what to put where I put my Django directory in line (2).

NOTE: Importing the Django models is really useful as this way I'm able to use all the query operations that Django provides and when I save or get something, it goes directly to the database configured in my Django project.

Comment: I'd recommend a REST service

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your scrapy settings configuration more generic.

The following settings works for me.

```
import os
import sys
import django

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), ".."))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'

django.setup()
```

You can further have a look at this.

https://github.com/bipul21/scrapy_django/blob/master/scrapy_project/scrapy_project/settings.py

It's a sample project where i have tied together django and scrapy.

Comment: Can you explain me how does it work? I don't see how would it work with one project in one heroku repo and the other one in another heroku repo.